# Changing dtype of view changes results of numpy functions without changing values of the array

Tags: python, numpy

I want the values of the np.mean function to be roughly the same, before and after the dtype change. The dtype has to remain float32.

```
array = np.random.randint(0, high=255, size=(3, 12000, 12000),dtype="int")

array = array[:,500:10000,500:10000]

array= array.reshape((-1,3))
# array.shape is now (90250000, 3)

print(np.mean(array,axis=0),array.dtype) # Nr.1

array = array.astype("float32")

print(np.mean(array,axis=0),array.dtype) # Nr.2
```

Results of the two print functions:

```
[127.003107   127.00156286 126.99015613] int32
[47.589664 47.589664 47.589664] float32
```

Adding a .copy() the view line has no effect. The size of the view effects the impact on the float mean. Changing the size in both the last dimensions to `[500:8000]` results in:

```
[76.35497 76.35497 76.35497] float32
```

Around `[500:5000]`and below both means are actually around the same.

Changing the code starting from the reshape line:

```
array= array.reshape((-1,3))

array_float = array.astype("float32")

print(np.all(array_float==array),array.dtype,array_float.dtype)
```

Results in:

```
True int32 float32
```

So if the values are the same, why are the results from np.mean different ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array:

```
In [50]: arr.shape, arr.dtype
Out[50]: ((90250000, 3), dtype('int32'))
```

You could have gotten this with `np.random.randint(0, high=255, size=(90250000,3),dtype="int")`.  In fact we don't need that size 3 dimension. Anyways it's just many numbers in the (0,255) range.

The expected mean:

```
In [51]: np.mean(arr, axis=0)
Out[51]: array([126.9822936 , 126.99682718, 126.99214526])
```

But notice what we get if we just sum those numbers:

```
In [52]: np.sum(arr, axis=0)
Out[52]: array([-1424749891, -1423438235, -1423860778])
```

The `int32` sum as overflowed and wrapped around.  There are too many numbers.  So `mean` must be doing something more sophisticated than simply summing and dividing by the count.

Taking mean on the `float32` gives the funny values:

```
In [53]: np.mean(arr.astype('float32'), axis=0)
Out[53]: array([47.589664, 47.589664, 47.589664], dtype=float32)
```

but `float64` matches the int case (but with a long conversion time):

```
In [54]: np.mean(arr.astype('float64'), axis=0)
Out[54]: array([126.9822936 , 126.99682718, 126.99214526])
```

It looks like the float `mean` is just doing the sum and divide method:

```
In [56]: np.sum(arr.astype('float64'), axis=0)
Out[56]: array([1.14601520e+10, 1.14614637e+10, 1.14610411e+10])    
In [57]: np.sum(arr.astype('float32'), axis=0)
Out[57]: array([4.2949673e+09, 4.2949673e+09, 4.2949673e+09], dtype=float32)

In [58]: Out[56]/arr.shape[0]
Out[58]: array([126.9822936 , 126.99682718, 126.99214526])    
In [59]: Out[57]/arr.shape[0]
Out[59]: array([47.58966533, 47.58966533, 47.58966533])
```

While the sum is within the range of `float32`:

```
In [60]: np.finfo('float32')
Out[60]: finfo(resolution=1e-06, min=-3.4028235e+38, max=3.4028235e+38, dtype=float32)
```

for some reason it is having problems getting the right values.

Note that the python `sum` has problems with the int version:

```
In [70]: sum(arr[:,0])
C:\Users\paul\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_1128\1456076714.py:1: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in long_scalars
  sum(arr[:,0])
Out[70]: -1424749891
```

There is a `math.fsum` that handles large sums better:

```
In [71]: math.fsum(arr[:,0])
Out[71]: 11460151997.0
```

Sum on the long ints also works fine:

```
In [72]: np.sum(arr.astype('int64'),axis=0)
Out[72]: array([11460151997, 11461463653, 11461041110], dtype=int64)
```

### From the `np.mean` docs:

```
dtype : data-type, optional
        Type to use in computing the mean.  For integer inputs, the default
        is `float64`; for floating point inputs, it is the same as the
        input dtype.

Notes
    -----
    The arithmetic mean is the sum of the elements along the axis divided
    by the number of elements.

    Note that for floating-point input, the mean is computed using the
    same precision the input has.  Depending on the input data, this can
    cause the results to be inaccurate, especially for `float32` (see
    example below).  Specifying a higher-precision accumulator using the
    `dtype` keyword can alleviate this issue.
```

Playing with the `dtype` parameter:

```
In [74]: np.mean(arr, axis=0, dtype='int32')
Out[74]: array([-15, -15, -15])

In [75]: np.mean(arr, axis=0, dtype='int64')
Out[75]: array([126, 126, 126], dtype=int64)

In [76]: np.mean(arr, axis=0, dtype='float32')
Out[76]: array([47.589664, 47.589664, 47.589664], dtype=float32)

In [77]: np.mean(arr, axis=0, dtype='float64')
Out[77]: array([126.9822936 , 126.99682718, 126.99214526])
```

The `-15` is explained by:

```
In [78]: -1424749891/arr.shape[0]
Out[78]: -15.786702393351801
```

In sum, if you want accurate results you need to use `float64`, either with the default `mean dtype`, or the appropriate `astype`.  Working with `float32` can give problems, especially with this many elements.

Answer (score 1):

Changing to "float64" solves the problem.

```
array = np.random.randint(0, high=255, size=(3, 12000, 12000),dtype="int")

array = array[:,500:10000,500:10000]

array= array.reshape((-1,3))
# array.shape is now (90250000, 3)

print(array.mean(axis=0),array.dtype) # Nr.1

array = array.astype("float64")
print(array.mean(axis=0),array.dtype) # Nr.2
```

Results in:

```
[126.98418438 126.9969912  127.00242922] int32
[126.98418438 126.9969912  127.00242922] float64
```

Comment: This was totally my error, what I should have added is that I require the array to stay in float32. I add that to the post, but I appreciate your help. The actual data is for open cv k-means that can only handle float32 as input.

Comment: to be honest I can't figure out why it's happening. but why won't you compute the mean on the array with dtype of int and change it to float32 before inserting it into the k means function?

Comment: It's not just the np.means, many other functions including the clustering algorithm have weird behavior that is mirrored by the np.means. It's just a basic indicator to illustrate the issue. Anyway, thanks for your attempt!